# Can I make mobile Safari open YouTube links in the browser?

Tags: iphone, safari, youtube

YouTube has a pretty decent mobile website, however any link to YouTube I see on the web always opens the link in the YouTube app, not there in the browser.

Is there a way to change that? It would be nice not to have to keep switching apps all the time. I checked in Settings and couldn't see anything. Echofon actually does it in its built in browser so I'm sure it must be possible.

Comment: Does "Open in New Tab" not work? I'd test it, but I'm not able to at the moment.

Comment: @timothymh No, when I press and hold the URL, the only options that come up are "open in YouTube" and "Copy".

Comment: How about "Copy" and then going to that URL directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Settings > General > Restrictions and untick the Youtube button. After that Youtube links will open in Safari and the app icon will disappear from the home screen.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot I'd asked this question - I'd actually found this exact solution elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can also manipulate the URL to solve this problem.

By directing away from `www` and towards `m`, this video link shows what to change:

- normal link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMed79
- mobile link: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=SMed79

:)

Answer (score 0):

This doe not seems to be able to fix via a simple setting or something. This [topic](http://forums.imore.com/jailbreaking-unlocking-hacks-themes-mods/196193-opening-youtube-links-website-not-app.html) at iMore says it used to be a beta-feature that has been taken out.

Appearently it has been asked at StackOverflow before, and in that [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512735/is-there-a-way-to-open-a-youttube-link-on-a-mobile-website-iphone-without-open) it was suggested to edit the URL manually:

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found a fix that seems to work. You go to a new tab in Safari and paste this: 
`https://m.youtube.com`

Then it will take you to the app. Close the app, go back to Safari and enter the link again. A pop up will come up asking if you want to open it in the app. Click cancel and then enter the link a third time. YouTube should load and work like normal on safari. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Disable youtube app background refresh